# How do I return a value from a GUI to another class varible?

Tags: python, blender

This is my first big project I am working on in python and I wanted to make a GUI that you can use to select a export location in blender and then click the export as FBX button to export it to the location. I have been looking around for awhile and honestly have gotten stuck, any help is appreciated.

I want to also use this for naming the object as well so I hope I can get this to work.

Please forgive me if I made any dumb mistakes.

```
import bpy   class ExPrt_Settings(bpy.types.PropertyGroup): file_path: bpy.props.StringProperty(default="", maxlen=1024, subtype="FILE_PATH")                                    

class Final_BL_Model(bpy.types.Panel): bl_label = "Model" bl_idname = "Final_BL_Model" bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D" bl_region_type = "UI" bl_category = "CBI"

  def draw(self, context): layout = self.layout obj = context.object



row = layout.row() row.label(text="CBI Model Panel", icon='BLENDER')   row = layout.row() row.label(text="Active object is: " + obj.name)

layout = self.layout row = layout.row()

eprt_dir = context.scene.eprt_dir row.prop(eprt_dir, "file_path")

row = layout.row() row.operator("addonname.myop_operator")

return str(eprt_dir)

class GUI_Export_Button(bpy.types.Operator, Final_BL_Model): bl_label = "Export as FBX" bl_idname = "addonname.myop_operator"

def execute(self, context): name = "test"

bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(eprt_dir + name + '.fbx', check_existing=True, filter_glob='*.fbx', use_selection=False, use_visible=False, use_active_collection=False, global_scale=1.0, apply_unit_scale=True, apply_scale_options='FBX_SCALE_NONE', use_space_transform=True, bake_space_transform=False, object_types={'ARMATURE', 'CAMERA', 'EMPTY', 'LIGHT', 'MESH', 'OTHER'}, use_mesh_modifiers=True, use_mesh_modifiers_render=True, mesh_smooth_type='OFF', use_subsurf=False, use_mesh_edges=False, use_tspace=False, use_triangles=False, use_custom_props=False, add_leaf_bones=True, primary_bone_axis='Y', secondary_bone_axis='X', use_armature_deform_only=False, armature_nodetype='NULL', bake_anim=True, bake_anim_use_all_bones=True, bake_anim_use_nla_strips=True, bake_anim_use_all_actions=True, bake_anim_force_startend_keying=True, bake_anim_step=1.0, bake_anim_simplify_factor=1.0, path_mode='AUTO', embed_textures=False, batch_mode='OFF', use_batch_own_dir=True, use_metadata=True, axis_forward='-Z', axis_up='Y')

return {'FINISHED'}


classes = [Final_BL_Model, GUI_Export_Button, ExPrt_Settings]
    def register(): for cls in classes: bpy.utils.register_class(cls) bpy.types.Scene.eprt_dir = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=ExPrt_Settings)

def unregister(): for cls in classes: bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls) del bpy.types.Scene.eprt_dir
 
    if __name__ == "__main__": register()
```

I have tried returning the variable yet for that to fail and looking around the web, I even got another addon that did what I want to see how they did it but I even failed there.

Comment: Please repost the code in a code block, not quotation.